# Elasticbeanstalk tomcat performance fluctuation

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat7, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have an application deployed to Tomcat 7 elasticbeanstalk (we have also tried tomcat 8). When we configure the application is using the [JDBCStore](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html) to back up sessions (RDS) we see fluctuations in performance during a load test, which go away when the JDBCStore is removed.

Here's a graph of requests from the ELB (load balancer) when using the JDBCStore

[image: Request count from the ELB with JDBCStore]

Here's a graph of request count using the same infrastructure when JDBCStore isn't used.
[image: Request count from the ELB withour JDBCStore]

We have the following JVM options set (we have tested removing some or all of them).

```
-Xmx1024m -Xms1024m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Duser.timezone=Europe/Dublin -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -Dorg.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.ACTIVITY_CHECK=true
```

Why would performance suffer so much under load when the JDBCStore is introduced?

**EDIT**

This issue was caused by the NAT in our VPC and **not** by the JDBCStore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was not caused by the JDBCStore. It was in fact caused by latency in the NAT used for our VPC in AWS. Making changes to this has resolved the issue.

**NAT changes**
We created a new subnet, 10.0.5.0, and allocated a dedicated NAT to it with a route path for that subnet only. We also switched from using a PV virtual server to a HVM virtual server and disable scatter-gather on the network card.